# The "meta" and orientation detect doesn't work in iPhone/iPad mail?

Tags: iphone, html, email, orientation, meta-tags

1. The meta such as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=600,initial-scale = 2.3,user-scalable=no">` doesn`t work in iPhone / iPad mail?
2. How to detect orientation in iPhone mail?
3. Is there any documentation about HTML & CSS in iPhone / iPad mail?

Comment: Are you talking about sending an HTML email that's read on an iOS deice that's not complying to those meta tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS 3 Media Queries** to detect Orientation of iPhone / iPad.

```
<!-- css -->
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) { 
    .landscape { display: none; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) { 
    .portrait { display: none; }
}

<!-- example markup -->
<h1 class="portrait">Your device orientation is "portrait"<h1>
<h1 class="landscape">Your device orientation is "landscape"<h1>
```

Comment: You can modify it to work with iPhone too! Portrait and Landscape orientation are there na? Use the `max-device-width` to 320 (640 for retina display)...

Comment: "You should be aware that orientation media query, although supported on the iPad, doesn’t work on the iPhone" -- http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css
And the size queries like width and device-width work in iPhone safari, but not work in iPhone mail content...